# PHPUnit - How to add vendor/bin into path?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, composer-php

I installed PHPUnit with composer. Everytime I run it, I have to call `vendor/bin/phpunit`. How can I put `vendor/bin` into path, so that next time I only need to call `phpunit` to run it?

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange on Windows 7 with WampServer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could add the current directory into your path.

For Linux/Mac add the following into your `.bash_profile`, Windows would be similar, alter the line below and add it into your `PATH`.

```
# include the current `vendor/bin` folder (Notice the `.` - This means current directory)
PATH="./vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Remember to restart your terminal or resource your `bash_profile`.

Now you should be able to run: `phpunit` and it will automatically look for it within `./vendor/bin` and if it exists it will execute using that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am using Windows 7 with WampServer. Where can I find `.bash_profile` file?

Comment: Checkout: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm OR http://superuser.com/questions/602872/how-do-i-modify-my-git-bash-profile-in-windows - It simply an "Environment Variable" we want to add.

Comment: This is the best solution because A) it works for every Laravel project installed on a machine, and B) it doesn't just make a shortcut for `phpunit` but rather all of the binaries within the `vendor/bin` directory.

Answer (score 5):

If you are running on Homestead (or some other Linux/Ubuntu system):

```
alias p='vendor/bin/phpunit'
```

Then you can just type `p` and it will run your tests

If you are using Homestead - you can add this alias to your `aliases` file so it is always there.

Comment: Is there a similar solution to this for a windows environment?

Answer (score 4):

Another easy solution, from the [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md#can-vendor-binaries-be-installed-somewhere-other-than-vendor-bin-), is to set your `bin-dir` setting to `./`. This will install the binary in your root directory.

```json
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "./"
}
```

Then you can just run `./phpunit`. I typically set `bin-dir` to `bin`, then type `bin/phpunit`. It's short enough for me.

If you already have phpunit installed, you will need to delete the `vendor/phpunit` directory and rerun `composer install` before composer will move the binary.